# sparkContext broadcast JedisPool not work

Tags: redis, apache-spark, broadcast, jedis, kryo

I was use sparkContext.broadcast in my spark streaming application for share redis connection pool(JedisPool).

The code like this:

```
lazy val redisPool = {
  val pool = Redis.createRedisPool(redisHost, redisPort)
  ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(pool)
}
```

Redis.createRedisPool is:

```
object Redis {

  def createRedisPool(host: String, port: Int, maxIdle: Int, maxTotal: Int, timeout: Int): JedisPool = {
    val pc = new JedisPoolConfig
    pc.setMaxIdle(maxIdle)
    pc.setMaxTotal(maxTotal)
    pc.setMaxWaitMillis(timeout)
    new JedisPool(pc, host, port)
  }

  def createRedisPool(host: String, port: Int): JedisPool = {
    createRedisPool(host, port, 5, 5, 5000)
  }
}
```

It works at local deploy mode, but when I run this at yarn/standalone mode like

```
spark-submit --master "yarn-client" --class ...
```

will get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1165)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:329)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:809)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming$.redisPool$lzycompute$1(AdSysStreaming.scala:84)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming$.redisPool$1(AdSysStreaming.scala:82)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming$.main(AdSysStreaming.scala:154)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming.main(AdSysStreaming.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I have tried set spark.serializer = org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer in my application, and then got error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException:        java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Serialization trace:
classes (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader)
classloader (java.security.ProtectionDomain)
context (java.security.AccessControlContext)
acc (org.apache.spark.executor.ExecutorURLClassLoader)
factoryClassLoader (org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool)
internalPool (redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:585)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:318)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:293)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:549)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:570)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:213)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:809)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming$.redisPool$lzycompute$1(AdSysStreaming.scala:85)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming$.redisPool$1(AdSysStreaming.scala:83)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming$.main(AdSysStreaming.scala:155)
    at org.culiu.bd.streaming.AdSysStreaming.main(AdSysStreaming.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:74)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:18)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:501)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.write(FieldSerializer.java:564)
    ... 39 more
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: is there is a reference to the context object inside the def extract body

Comment: yah, ssc is defined as a StreamingContext instance, ssc.sparkContext reference to SparkContext

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem here is that the `redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool` class is not serializable.  This doesn't seem like a Spark-specific issue, since I think that any attempt to serialize that class would fail.

Comment: it's any solution?